# Strong parameters with nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I have the following params and cannot get the strong parameters to work.

Here's my basic code, runnable in the Rails console for simplicity:

```
json = {
  id: 1,
  answers_attributes: {
    c1: { id: "", content: "Hi" },
    c2: { id: "", content: "Ho" }
  }
}

params = ActionController::Parameters.new(json)
```

Everything I've read says the following should work, but it only gives me the `id` and an empty hash of `answers_attributes`:

```
params.permit(:id, answers_attributes: [:id, :content])
=> { "id"=>1, "answers_attributes"=>{} }
```

If I instead manually list `c1` and `c2` (like below) it works, but this is really stupid because I don't know how many answers the user will supply, and this is a lot of duplication:

```
params.permit(:id, answers_attributes: { c1: [:id, :content], c2: [:id, :content] })
=> {"id"=>1, "answers_attributes"=>{"c1"=>{"id"=>"", "content"=>"Hi"}, "c2"=>{"id"=>"", "content"=>"Ho"}}}
```

I've tried replacing `c1` and `c2` with `0` and `1`, but I still have to manually supply the `0` and `1` in my permit statement.

How can I permit an unknown length array of nested attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's done with syntax like:

```
answers_attributes: [:id, :content]
```

The problem is the keys you are using in the `answers_attributes`. They are expected to be the ids of the `answers_attributes` or in the case of new records `0`.

Changing these gives your expected outcome:

```
json = {
  id: 1,
  answers_attributes: {
    "1": { id: "", content: "Hi" },
    "2": { id: "", content: "Ho" }
  }
}

params = ActionController::Parameters.new(json)

params.permit(:id, answers_attributes:[:id, :content])
=>  {"id"=>1, "answers_attributes"=>{"1"=>{"id"=>"", "content"=>"Hi"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"", "content"=>"Ho"}}}
```

Edit: It appears that 0 is not the only key, I mean what if you have two `new` records. I use [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) and it appears to use a very long random number.

Comment: You specifically say `"in the case of new records"`. Does this also apply to edited records?

Comment: Edited records are not new so you would have the `id` as the key.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed does appear to do the trick. It's odd that it must be a string representation of a number instead of an actual number, but I can get it to work. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @TopherFangio I don't think they have to be strings. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your `answers_attributes` contains c1 and c2 which are not permitted. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

**WAY 1:** You can pass the nested attributes as array of hashes.

```
json = {
  id: 1,
  answers_attributes: [ { id: "", content: "Hi" }, { id: "", content: "Ho" } ]
}
```

Now `params.permit(:id, answers_attributes: [:id, :content])` gives

```
{"id"=>1, "answers_attributes"=>[{"id"=>"", "content"=>"Hi"}, {"id"=>"", "content"=>"Ho"}]}
```

**WAY 2:** You can pass as hash of hashes like

```
json = {
  id: 1,
  answers_attributes: {
    c1: { id: "", content: "Hi" },
    c2: { id: "", content: "Ho" }
  }
}
```

Both **WAY 1** and **WAY 2** have the same effect in the model level. But `permit` doesn't allow the values to pass unless the keys are explicitly specified. So `c1` and `c2` will not be permitted unless explicitly specified like

```
params.permit(:id, answers_attributes: [c1: [:id, :content], c2: [:id, :content]])
```

which is really a pain in the ass.

Comment: `c1` and `c2` are indeed valid for the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as this has always worked and the data was being saved before I started using `permit`. The problem is that the `permit` call doesn't understand this syntax and wasn't passing it along to the model to be saved. **Edit: Of note, your WAY 2 above also doesn't work with permit if you use that JSON.**

Comment: Thanks for notifying. As  @TopherFangio mentioned, permit doesn't allow the value to pass unless we explicitly specified the key. I will edit my answer.