# Strong Parameters: How to permit a hash of arbitrarily structured hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I want to permit a the `queries` param. But I only know it's a hash with nested hashes inside it. I don't know which keys are inside it. It could e.g. look like this:

```
Started PATCH "/en/foos/5ca7a1b883c336410fb0923c" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-04-09 09:13:46 +0200
Processing by FoosController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"queries"=>"{\r\n  \"query1\": {\r\n    \"query\" : {\r\n      \"order_number\" : {\r\n        \"$in\" : [\"1\", \"2\"]\r\n      },\r\n      \"name\" : \"Batman\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"projection\" : {\r\n      \"_id\" : 1,\r\n      \"order_number\" : 1\r\n    },\r\n    \"sort\" : {\r\n      \"order_number\" : 1\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"query2\" : {\r\n  }\r\n}", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"5ca7a1b883c336410fb0923c"}
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 0.6ms)
```

I need to parse the params before moving on:

```rb
params[:queries] = JSON.parse(params[:queries])
# =>
# {
#   "query1": {
#     "query": {
#       "order_number": {
#         "$in": ["1", "2"]
#       },
#       "name": "Batman"
#     },
#     "projection": {
#       "_id": 1,
#       "order_number": 1
#     },
#     "sort": {
#       "order_number": 1
#     }
#   },
#   "query2": {
#   }
# }
```

After the parsing I want to permit it, but `params.permit([{queries: {}}])` don't permit all the nested hashes.

So how do I simply permit the `queries` param with any nested content?

Comment: did you try params.permit(queries: {}) ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't cover the content of the nested hashes.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766406/strong-parameters-with-nested-hash ... By default strong params expects the nested attribute values .